# Trying to get property 'amount' of non-object in view sev.blade.php

Tags: laravel

below is my PaymentController

```
public function handleGatewayCallback(Request $request){

$paymentDetails = Paystack::getPaymentData();
return view('sev', ['details' => $paymentDetails]);
```

now in my view page, I simply loop:

```
@foreach($details as $detail) {{detail->amount}} @endforeach.
```

but I get the error: trying to get property of 'amount' of non object in my view. please how do I get all the json data contained in $paymentDetails and save it to my database.

Comment: `detail->amount` change to `$detail->amount`

Comment: I did that but still get the same error

Comment: what you get if you change {{detail->amount}} to {{dd($detail)}}

Comment: What is getPaymentData()? And what do you get from that?

Comment: Post Paystack::getPaymentData(); Without seeing it, I'm thinking your blade should be {{$detail['amount']}} you are most likely returning an array if laravel is giving you a non-object error.

Comment: @Lipe Tuga: I saw a display on my view named 'true' when I changed it to {{dd(detail)}}. Bak87: that is the payment data comprising of the amount, date, currency, etc. its a json. polaris; how do I change that array, so I can save amount, date,currency,etc in their  own column in my table in my database?